# Distinguishing niece from sister using shared percentage DNA

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis

On Ancestry who I thought was my niece my oldest sisters child shared 49% -56% dna how is that possible ?

I also have a first cousin who shares 26% yet his sister only shares 6% why is that

Answer (score 0):

From your question I am unable to discern which individuals you are listing each of those percentage match values for. I am also not sure why you are expressing a range of 49%-56% rather than a single value.

However, at DNA Painter:

- a percentage of [49% equates to 3,646cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/3646) and suggests a Parent-Child  relationship is 100% likely.
- a percentage of 56% equates to 4,166cM, does not suggest a relationship, but does say:

> Assuming no pedigree collapse or endogamy, and that you're related in
> just one way, the furthest back you might need to go to find common
> ancestors for a match of 4166cM is Grandparent level. The connection
> may be closer.

- a percentage of [26% equates to 1,934cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1934) and suggests several relationships may be possible.
- a percentage of [6% equates to 446cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/446) and suggests many relationships may be possible.